# How do the authors deduce this weaker version of Transfinite Recursion?

Tags: set-theory, proof-explanation, ordinals, transfinite-recursion

My question is about a proof of **Theorem 4.12** given in the text *Introduction to Set Theory* by Hrbacek and Jech.

The authors first prove **Theorems 4.9**, **4.10**, and **4.11**. For reference, I quote these theorems below.

---

> Let $V$ be the class of all sets, $\operatorname{Ord}$ be the class of all ordinals, and $G:V\to V$ be a class function.

**Theorem 4.9: Transfinite Recursion Theorem**

> There exists a class function $F:\operatorname{Ord}\to V$ such that $F(\alpha)=G(F\restriction \alpha)$ for all $\alpha\in\operatorname{Ord}$.

**Theorem 4.10: Transfinite Recursion Theorem, Parametric Version**

> There exists a class function $F:\operatorname{Ord}\to V$ such that $F(z,\alpha)=G(z,F_z\restriction \alpha)$ for all $\alpha\in\operatorname{Ord}$ and $z\in V$ where $F_z\restriction \alpha:=\{\langle\beta,F(z,\beta)\rangle\mid\beta<\alpha\}$.

**Theorem 4.11:**

> Let $G_1,G_2,G_3$ be class functions from $V$ to $V$. There exists a class function $F:\operatorname{Ord}\to V$ such that
>
> (1) $F(0)=G_1(\emptyset)$
>
> (2) $F(\alpha+1)=G_2(F(\alpha))$ for all $\alpha\in\operatorname{Ord}$
>
> (3) $F(\alpha)=G_3(F\restriction\alpha)$ for all limit $\alpha\neq 0$

---

Then they say *A parametric version of **Theorem 4.11** is straightforward and we leave it to the reader*. From my attempt, the **parametric version of Theorem 4.11** is as follows (Honestly, I'm not sure if my attempt is correct or not)

> Let $G_1,G_2,G_3$ be class functions from $V$ to $V$. There exists a class function $F$ such that, for all $z\in V$
>
> $F(z,0)=G_1(z,\emptyset)$
>
> $F(z,\alpha+1)=G_2(z,F_z(\alpha))$ for all $\alpha\in\operatorname{Ord}$
>
> $F(z,\alpha)=G_3(z,F_z\restriction\alpha)$ for all limit $\alpha\neq 0$

Next they make use of this **parametric version of Theorem 4.11** in the proof of **Theorem 4.12**.

**Theorem 4.12:**

> For any set $a$, there is a unique infinite sequence $(f_n\mid n\in \Bbb N)$ such that
>
> (1) $f_0=a$
>
> (2) $f_{n+1}=G(f_n,n)$ for all $n\in \Bbb N$

The proof for **Theorem 4.12** given in the text is as follows:

> Let $G:V\to V$ be a class function. We want to find, for every set $a$, a sequence $(f_n\mid n\in \Bbb N)$ such that $f_0=a$ and $f_{n+1}=G(f_n,n)$ for all $n\in \Bbb N$. By the **parametric version of the Transfinite Recursion Theorem 4.11**, there is class function $F$ such that $F(0)=a$ and $F(n+1)=G(F(n),n)$ for all $n\in \Bbb N$. Now we apply the Axiom of Replacement: There exists a sequence $(f_n\mid n\in \Bbb N)$ that is equal to $F\restriction \omega$ and the Theorem follows.

---

I don't understand how the **parametric version of Theorem 4.11** is used to derive the class function $F$ in the proof of **Theorem 4.12**. Can someone please help me fill in the blanks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do not actually need the parametric version of Theorem 4.11. In fact, Theorem 4.11 implies Theorem 4.12. This is what your textbook says.

Let $G_1$, $G_2$ and $G_3$ is a class function such that
$G_1(0)=(\{(0,a)\}, 0)$, 
$$G_2(x) = \begin{cases}(G(f,n),n+1) & \text{if $x=(f,n)$ for some $n$ and $f$,}\\ \varnothing & \text{otherwise,}\end{cases}$$
and $G_3(x)=\varnothing$. You can see that $F(n) = (f_n,n)$. That is, the sequence of the first component of $F(n)$ is our desired sequence.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! Maybe i'm wrong. Please have a check on my reasoning: From Theorem 4.11, we have $F(n+1)=G_2(F(n))$. But we are not sure that $F(n)=(f,n)$ for some $f$ (it's obvious that $(f,n)$ is a pair, but $F(n)$ is not necessarily a pair). As a result, we are not sure if $F(n)=(f,n)$ for some $f$ or otherwise. Thus we are unable to apply the definition of $G_2$ to $F(n)$.

Comment: @LeAnhDung You can prove $F(n)$ is always of the form $(f,n)$ by induction for $n$.

Comment: Oh I got it. I have reformulated your answer into a detailed proof and posted it as an answer below so that I can truly understand your ideas. Could you please verify it? Maybe I'm wrong, but I think $G_1(0)=(a, 0)$ rather than $G_1(0)=(\{(0,a)\}, 0)$ so as to $f_0=a$. If not, $f_0=\{(0,a)\}$, which is not as we desired.

Comment: @LeAnhDung I think your proof and observation on my error are correct.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! Just for my curiosity: Is it possible to utilize the parametric version of Theorem 4.11 rather than Theorem 4.11 to prove Theorem 4.12 as suggested by the authors of my textbook?

Comment: @LeAnhDung You can easily prove the parametric version of Theorem 4.11 from Theorem 4.11; by just taking some modification on $G_i$s.

Comment: Hi! I meant to prove Theorem 4.12 by the parametric version of Theorem 4.11, not to prove the parametric version of Theorem 4.11 by Theorem 4.11. I'm still obsessed by the authors' proof.

Comment: Ah... I misunderstood your question. The parametric version of Theorem 4.11 implies Theorem 4.11, so my proof is in fact a proof you want (but I do not think you count it as a valid one.) I have no idea how to use the parameter $z$ for easier proof.

Comment: That's why i posted another question :) Since you meant *The parametric version of Theorem 4.11 implies Theorem 4.11*, could you please have a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2970783/are-these-two-parametric-versions-of-transfinite-recursion-equivalent)?

Answer (score 1):

On the basis of Hanul Jeon's answer. I present a detailed solution here. All credits are given to Hanul Jeon.

---

We define $G_1,G_2$ as follows

$G_1(x) = \begin{cases}(a, 0) & \text{if } x=0\\ \varnothing & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

$G_2(x) = \begin{cases}(G(f,n),n+1) & \text{if $x=(f,n)$ for some $f\in V$ and $n\in\Bbb N$}\\ \varnothing & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

By **Theorem 4.11**, there exists a function $F$ such that $F(0)=G_1(0)$ and $F(\alpha+1)=G_2(F(\alpha))$ for all $\alpha\in\operatorname{Ord}$. It follows that $F(0)=(a,0)$ and $F(n+1)=G_2(F(n))$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$.

We prove by induction that $F(n)$ is of the form $(f_n,n)$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$. It's trivial that $F(0)=(a, 0)$ is of the form $(f_0,0)$. Assume that $F(n)$ is of the form $(f_n,n)$. Then $F(n+1)=G_2(F(n))=$ $G_2(f_n,n)=(G(f_n,n),n+1)=(f_{n+1},n+1)$ where $f_{n+1}=G(f_n,n)$.

Then we extract the sequence $(f_n\mid n\in\Bbb N)$ from $(F(n)\mid n\in\Bbb N)$. It's clear that $f_0=0$ and that $f_{n+1}=G(f_n,n)$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$.