# How do Hrbacek and Jech derive the class function $F$ in Theorem 4.12 from Theorem 4.11?

Tags: set-theory, proof-explanation, ordinals, transfinite-recursion

My question is about a proof of **Theorem 4.12** given in the text *Introduction to Set Theory* by Hrbacek and Jech.

---

> Let $V$ be the class of all sets, $\operatorname{Ord}$ be the class of all ordinals, and $G,G_1,G_2,G_3$ be class functions from $V$ to $V$.

**Theorem 4.11:**

> There exists a class function $F:V\times\operatorname{Ord}\to V$ such that, for all $z\in V$
>
> $F(z,0)=G_1(z,\emptyset)$
>
> $F(z,\alpha+1)=G_2(z,F_z(\alpha))$ for all $\alpha\in\operatorname{Ord}$, with $F_z(\alpha):=F(z,\alpha)$
>
> $F(z,\alpha)=G_3(z,F_z\restriction\alpha)$ for all $\alpha\neq 0$ limit, with $F_z\restriction \alpha:=\{\langle\beta,F(z,\beta)\rangle\mid\beta<\alpha\}$

**Theorem 4.12:**

> For any set $a$, there is a unique infinite sequence $(f_n\mid n\in \Bbb N)$ such that
>
> (1) $f_0=a$
>
> (2) $f_{n+1}=G(f_n,n)$ for all $n\in \Bbb N$

The proof for **Theorem 4.12** is given in the text as follows:

> Let $G:V\to V$ be a class function. We want to find, for every set $a$, a sequence $(f_n\mid n\in \Bbb N)$ such that $f_0=a$ and $f_{n+1}=G(f_n,n)$ for all $n\in \Bbb N$. By **Theorem 4.11**, there is class function $F$ such that $F(0)=a$ and $F(n+1)=G(F(n),n)$ for all $n\in \Bbb N$. Now we apply the Axiom of Replacement: There exists a sequence $(f_n\mid n\in \Bbb N)$ that is equal to $F\restriction \omega$ and the Theorem follows.

---

I don't understand how **Theorem 4.11** is used to derive the class function $F$ in the proof of **Theorem 4.12**. Can someone elaborate on how to obtain the desired $F$?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I am bit surprised as you post the same question I have answered. Does my answer insufficient?

Comment: Hi @HanulJeon! your answer in that post is great and sufficient. I post this question to ask for a proof from a different perspective ^^

Comment: You should not repost the same question. If you are not satisfied with the answers you get, and want more answers, you can put a bounty on your original question. Reposting the question, and worse still without linking to the older question, is against SE guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way. define auxilliary functions $G_1$, $G_2$ and $G_3$. To get what you want. And afterwards you have to modify the resulting function a bit.
Define $G_1(z,\emptyset)=\langle z,0\rangle$, and $G_2(z,\langle x,y\rangle) = \langle G(x,y),y\cup\{y\}\rangle$, and $G_3(z,x)=G(x)$ (these are the important cases, in all other cases set the value to $\emptyset$.
Theorem 4.11 gives you a function $H$ that satisfies its conclusions.
Note that $H(z,0)=\langle z,0\rangle$,
that $H(z,n+1) = G_2(z,H(z,n)) = \langle G(H_1(z,n)),H_2(z,n)), H_2(z,n)+1\rangle$ ($H_1$ and $H_2$ are the coordinates of $H$..
Prove by induction that $H_2(z,n)=n$ for all $n$, so that $H(z,n+1)$ is actually equal to $\langle G(H_1(z,n)), n+1\rangle$.
Finally then define $F(n)=H_1(a,n)$, that $F$ is as needed in the proof.

Because you can use ordered pairs you can code a lot of stuff into this kind of recursions.

Comment: Thank you so much for your proof! I really got ans appreciate it. I have a seemingly similar problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2970783/are-these-two-parametric-versions-of-transfinite-recursion-equivalent). I have tried to give it a shot. If you don't mind, please help me verify my attempt. Thank you for your dedicated help!

Answer (score 0):

I fill in @hartkp's proof with details. All credits are given to @hartkp.

---

\begin{align}&G_1(x)=\begin{cases}
\langle z,0\rangle&\text{if }x=\langle z,\emptyset\rangle\\\emptyset&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}\\\\&G_2(x)=\begin{cases}
\langle G(y,\alpha),\alpha\cup\{\alpha\}\rangle&\text{if }x=(z,\langle y,\alpha\rangle)\\\emptyset&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}\\&G_3(x)=\begin{cases}
G(\alpha)&\text{if }x=(z,\alpha)\\\emptyset&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}\end{align}

By **Theorem 4.11**, there exists a class function $H:V\times\operatorname{Ord}\to V$ such that, for all $z\in V$

- $H(z,0)=G_1(z,\emptyset)$
- $H(z,\alpha+1)=G_2(z,H_z(\alpha))$ for all $\alpha\in\operatorname{Ord}$
- $H(z,\alpha)=G_3(z,H_z\restriction\alpha)$ for all $\alpha\neq 0$ limit

First, we prove that $H(a,n)$ is of the form of an ordered pair $\langle f_n,n\rangle$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$.

- $H(a,0)=G_1(a,\emptyset)=\langle a,\emptyset\rangle=\langle a,0\rangle=\langle f_0,0\rangle$ where $f_0=a$. Thus the statement is trivially true for $n=0$.
- Assume that $H(a,n)$ is of the form of an ordered pair $\langle f_n,n\rangle$. Then $H(a,n+1)=G_2(a,H_a(n))=G_2(a,H(a,n))=G_2(a,\langle f_n,n\rangle)$ $=\langle G(f_n,n),n\cup\{n\}\rangle=\langle G(f_n,n),n+1\rangle=\langle f_{n+1},n+1\rangle$ where $f_{n+1}=G(f_n,n)$. Thus the statement is true for $n+1$.

From $(H(a,n)\mid n\in\Bbb N)$, we extract the desired sequence $(f_n\mid n\in\Bbb N)$.